# How can I use CSS3 transform on a span?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have an **inline element** (a `<span>`) nested in a `<h1>` tag. I applied a **transform** property to the `h1` ( `skew` so it looks like a parallelogram).
I need to **transform** the `<span>` tag to "unskew" it and its text. But this only seems to work in IE.

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/27JAP/) of the HTML and CSS:

```css
h1 {
  background: #f00;
  padding: .25em .5em;
  text-align: right;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
}
h1 span {
  color: #fff;
  transform: skew(15deg);
}
```

```html
<h1><span>This is a Title</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

**Explanation:**
A `<span>` or a link (`<a>`) are inline elements and the **transform property doesn't apply to inline elements**.
Here is the [list of transformable elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transformable-element) *from the CSS Transforms Module Level 1*.

**Solution:**
Set the display property of the span to `inline-block` or `block`. This will let you apply transforms to the span element.
It also works for other inline elements like `<a> <em> <strong>`... (see the [list of inline elements on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Elements)).

Here is a demo with the `<span>` and link `<a>` elements :

```css
h1 {
  background: teal;
  padding: .25em .5em;
  margin: 1em;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
}
h1 span,
h1 a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;  /* <- ADD THIS */
  transform: skew(15deg);
}
```

```html
<h1><span>This is a span in a title</span></h1>
<h1><a href="#">This is a link in a title</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

A little late here, but you can set

```
h1 span{
   position:absolute;
}
```

Then use the CSS3 transform properties normally. Demo:

```css
h1 {
  background: #f00;
  padding: .25em .5em;
  text-align: right;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  height: 40px;
}

h1 span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: skew(15deg);
}
```

```html
<h1><span>This is a Title</span></h1>
```