# Left align skewed text in container

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, skew

I have to apply skew and rotate on an element. It works fine but the **skewed text isn't left aligned** in it's container (see the result image):

[image: Skewed text isn't left aligned]

The text on the left is overflowing the container: the H (from "Hello") and the T (from "The") alignment is not right.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Skewed text left aligned on a vertical line]

```css
.skew-parent-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.skew-text {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="skew-parent-wrapper">
  <h1 class="skew-text">Hello Welcome to the skew text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Essentially **you can't**. A `transform` is a purely *visual* change...it does not affect how elements are laid out or sized. You will require Javascript I suspect.

Comment: Do you know any plugins which has this kind of effect ?

Comment: Nope and that would be off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 8):

One way of **aligning the skewed text on a vertical line** is to manualy set a negative [text-indent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent). This technique also requires to set a [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) on bottom left :

```css
.skew-parent-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.skew-text {
  transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  text-indent: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skew-parent-wrapper">
  <h1 class="skew-text">Hello Welcome to the skew text</h1>
</div>
```

This technique works on text that wraps only on two lines. **For text with more than 2 lines**, you will need to wrap each line in a tag (like a `<span>`) :

```css
.skew-parent-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.skew-text span{
  display:block;
  transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-30deg, 0deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="skew-parent-wrapper">
  <h1 class="skew-text">
    <span>Hello Welcome to the</span>
    <span>skewed text with</span>
    <span>several lines many</span>
    <span>many many lines</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

*Note that you need to set the `<span>` to `display:block` because [transforms don't apply on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24961795/1811992).*

Answer (score 0):

With rotation and skew you will get a behaviour like perspective so the oversizing is a result of that. 
You need to manually scale down your skew-text and then disable the overflow of its container so you won't see any overlapping text.

That's the only idea for me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to achieve the alignment if you use a rotation as transform.

Use a skew to get the inclined lines. You can (to some extent) get the angle on the letters using italics

Also, there is no need for all the vendor specific tranforms

```css
.skew-parent-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.skew-text {
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div class="skew-parent-wrapper">
  <h1 class="skew-text">Hello Welcome to the skewed text that can span several lines</h1>
</div>
```