# Cannot read property 'style' of null -- Uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, html

I got the error "Cannot read property 'style' of null" and I tried everything I put the script in the bottom of the HTML and I still got the error. what do I do?

Line with error:

```
document.getElementById("span").style.webkitTransform = v 
"rotate"+p+"("+ps.value+"deg)"
```

```js
function r(p) {
  var ps;
  ps = document.getElementById(p);
  document.getElementById("span").style.webkitTransform = "rotate" + p + "(" + ps.value + "deg)"
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="div">
    <span class="span"></span>
  </div>
</div>
X:<input type="range" id="X" onchange="r('X');" value="45" /> Y:
<input type="range" id="Y" onchange="r('Y')" /> Z:
<input type="range" id="Z" onchange="r('Z')" />
```

Comment: Because you do not have an ID you have a CLASS

Comment: i don't see any `id` named as `span` in posted code

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: `document.getElementById("span")` where is the element with ID `span`

Comment: You cannot transform an inline element anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not have an ID but a class
2. You need to not try to transform an inline element like a span

[How can I use CSS3 transform on a span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961795/how-can-i-use-css3-transform-on-a-span)

```js
function r(p) {
  var ps;
  ps = document.getElementById(p);
  var rot = "rotate" + p + "(" + ps.value + "deg)";
  console.log(rot);
  document.querySelector(".div").style.webkitTransform = rot;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="div">
    <span class="span">shfasjdfhalsdjfh</span>
  </div>
</div>
X:<input type="range" id="X" onchange="r('X');" value="45" /> Y:
<input type="range" id="Y" onchange="r('Y')" /> Z:
<input type="range" id="Z" onchange="r('Z')" />
```

Comment: I fixed it I just had to change the classes to ids now its fixed

Comment: Just will need to use classes if you have more than one with the same id which must be unique