# CSS transform does not get applied on elements selected by :nth-child()

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transforms

Consider the following HTML:

```
<p>
  <span> A </span>
  <span> A </span>
  <span> A </span>
</p>
```

Now try applying this CSS on it:

```
p span:nth-of-type(2) {transform: rotateX( 180deg ) ; color: blue }
```

You will see that the color has been changed on the second span, but the transform property has not. Could anyone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span>` by default has `display: inline` and you need `display:block` or `display:inline-block` for `transform` to take effect.

```css
p span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateX( 180deg);
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span> A </span>
  <span> A </span>
  <span> A </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the reason is that css transform works only on "block" elements. Since  is an "inline"element, it will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961795/how-can-i-use-css3-transform-on-a-span) post, span is an inline element and the transform property will not work unless you use "display:block;", or in your case "display:inline-block;"

Change your css to this:

```
p span:nth-of-type(2){
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child` won't apply to the class, just the element only it works. You need to apply to the children first then it works fine.

```css
p span:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateX( 180deg);
 }
```

```html
<p>
  <span> A </span>
  <span> A </span>
  <span> A </span>
</p>
```