# gsap timeline in react

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I am new to gsap and trying to make some animations on it, but when I set gsap to my header it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";

  let tl = gsap.timeline();

  useEffect(() => {
    tl.from(".lastHeader", { y: 50, duration: 1 });
  }, []);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Check does element `.lastHeader` was transformed? Try to add `let tl = gsap.timeline({paused: true})` and then after create `tl` (`tl.from(...)`) try to call `tl.play()`.  Or try to add `let tl = gsap.timeline({repeat: -1, yoyo: true})` and check does animation play infinite

Comment: `.lastHeader` is a span element, thats why it doesnt work, but why? I tried using it with div element, it works fine. Why doesn't it work with span element?

Comment: Because css transform does not apply to inline elements, you can change css to `display: inline-block` more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/24962108/14135825

Answer (score 0):

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";

tl = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    tl.current = gsap.timeline();
    .from(".lastHeader", { y: 50, duration: 1 });
  }, []);
```

You can use code like this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid creating a new timeline on every render, it's important to create the timeline inside an effect and store it in a ref.

This will also allow u to access the timeline in a different effect.

see example here:

```
function App() {
  const el = useRef();
  const q = gsap.utils.selector(el);
  const tl = useRef();
      
  useEffect(() => {            
    
    tl.current = gsap.timeline()
      .to(q(".box"), {
        rotate: 360
      })
      .to(q(".circle"), {
        x: 100
      });

  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="app" ref={el}>
      <Box>Box</Box>
      <Circle>Circle</Circle>
    </div>
  );
}
```

More info here: https://greensock.com/react/

Answer (score 0):

You have to define timeLine variable outside of `useLayoutEffect`.

```
const comp = useRef(null);
const tl = useRef<gsap.core.Timeline | null>(null);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const ctx = gsap.context(() => {
    tl.current = gsap
      .timeline()
      .from("your-element", {
        duration: 4,
        delay: 0.4,
        opacity: 0,
        y: 200,
        ease: "power3.inOut",
      })
     }, comp);
     return () => ctx.revert(); // cleanup
 }, []);
```

Comment: why useLayoutEffect? asfik, gsap schedules animations on a different lifecycle than react's