# Add styles using button to Span created using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to rotate a span created using JavaScript on a button click, the class gets added to the span but the rotate doesn't effect the span.

```
<p>Click the button to create a SPAN element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Spin Span</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var t = document.createTextNode("This is a span element.");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  x.setAttribute("id","firstPracPara");
}
function myFunction2() {
var element = document.getElementById("firstPracPara");
element.classList.add("rotate");
}
</script>

<style>
.rotate{
transform: rotate(20deg);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use CSS3 transform on a span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961795/how-can-i-use-css3-transform-on-a-span)

Answer (score 1):

With your current code it is impossible because a `span` is a `inline` element.

If you want to complete what you asking you need to put `display: block` on your span element.

````
<style>
span { display: block };
.rotate{
transform: rotate(20deg);
}
</style>```
````

Comment: that works but do you know how I can do it for each span created?

Comment: You need to specify each span created it is a `display: block`

Comment: https://codepen.io/ah5ann/pen/JjpEOBp i have done

Comment: Nope, it work only for the first span :) You need to loop on all spans