# Add class using button for each span created using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have gotten an inline element to spin after it has been created using JavaScript by adding a new class to it but I am trying to add that spinning effect to all spans created using JavaScript, currently it is only doing it for 1.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var t = document.createTextNode("This is a span element.");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  x.setAttribute("id", "firstPracPara");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function myFunction2() {
  var element = document.getElementById("firstPracPara");
  element.classList.add("rotate");
}
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}

.firstPracPara {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: spin;
  -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-name: spin;
  -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create a SPAN element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Spin Span</button>
```

I have never used forEach before but i feel like this is the way to do it.

```
x.forEach(function (e) {
    element.classList.add("rotate");
});
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have more than one element with any given id value. It must be unique. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

Comment: @Asn In `myFunction2` you are only getting the single element and adding rotate class to it. You can either add the `rotate` class while creating the element or use `.querySelectorAll` to get all elements you want to add rotation to.

Answer (score 2):

Try using like this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("span");
  var t = document.createTextNode("This is a span element.");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function myFunction2() {
let newSpan = document.querySelectorAll('span');
newSpan.forEach((e) => e.classList.add("rotate"));

}
```

```css
span { 
display: block;
}
.firstPracPara{
transform: rotate(10deg);
}
.rotate{
 -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create a SPAN element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Spin Span</button>
```

Comment: got an email I can contact you by about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll` wisely. You can ignore already rotated spans.

See the Snippet below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var t = document.createTextNode("This is a span element.");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  x.setAttribute("class", "firstPracPara");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function myFunction2() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".firstPracPara:not(.rotate)");
  elements.forEach(_element=>{
    _element.classList.add("rotate");
  });
}
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}

#firstPracPara {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: spin;
  -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-name: spin;
  -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create a SPAN element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Spin Span</button>
```

Comment: got an email I can contact you by about this problem?

Comment: sure. happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `transform` on `span`. See this link for more explanations.
[How can I use CSS3 transform on a span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961795/how-can-i-use-css3-transform-on-a-span)

As for your other question:

**main.js**

```
const elements= document.querySelectorAll('.className');

elements.forEach(elemen => element.classList.add('new class name');
```

Comment: I added transform to the span by using display:block to one of them but its not adding for all of them

Comment: Typo: `elemen =>`. Also `new class name` cannot contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the spans in a QuerySelector, then apply your class for each of them like this :

```
function myFunction2() {
  spans = document.querySelectorAll('span')
  spans.forEach(span => span.classList.add("rotate"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `getElementById` to retrieve elements to change, but this function returns at most only one element.

> The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be
> unique in the whole document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

You could use a class instead:

```
x.classList.add("item");
```

Then:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].classList.add("rotate");
}
```

Or, if you want to use `forEach`, transform the `HTMLCollection` to an `Array` with `Array.from`:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
Array.from(elements).forEach(element => {
  element.classList.add("rotate");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be uniq, that's why  document.getElementById returns only one element.

In this case you should try to

```
x.setAttribute("class", "firstPracPara");
```

Now you can easily add new classes using below code

```
document.querySelectorAll('.className').forEach((elem) {
   elem.classList.add("rotate");
});
```